# Java - Why can't I use charAt() to see if a char equals another?

Tags: java, string, char, equals

I want to see if a character in my string equals a certain other char value but I do not know what the char in the string is so I have used this:

```
if ( fieldNames.charAt(4) == "f" )
```

But I get the error:

```
"Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'char', 'jav.lang.String'"
```

But `"g" == "h"` seems to work and I know you can use `'=='` with char types.

Is there another way to do this correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: `"f"`is a String, `'f'` is a char.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is the correct way to write that:

```
if ( fieldNames.charAt(4) == 'f' )
```

In your original version, `"f"` is a `String` and `fieldNames.charAt(4)` is a `char`, and you cannot compare a `String` with a `char` using `==`.  If you write `'f'` instead of `"f"` (as above) you will be comparing a `char` with a `char`.

Note that `"g" == "h"` is also accepted by the compiler because both `"g"` and `"h"` are `String` objects.  However, you shouldn't do that.  You should use `"g".equals("h")` instead.  To understand why, please read [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/).  (The short version is that `someString == otherString` comparisons will *often* give an unexpected answer!)

By contrast `'g' == 'h'` is both accepted by the compiler AND correct code.

---

More background: a Java `String` literal is surrounded by double quotes, but a `char` literal is surrounded by single quotes; e.g.

```
String s = "g";
char c = 'g';
```

A `char` value consists of one and only one character<sup>1</sup> but `String` value can contain more than one  character ... or zero characters.

```
String s2 = "gg";  valid
char c2 = 'gg';  not valid

String s3 = "";  valid
char c3 = '';  not valid
```

---

<sup>1 - Actually, calling them characters is technically a stretch.  A `char` ... or a value returned by `String.getChar` is actually an unsigned 16 bit number.  But Java natively uses Unicode, and 16 bits is not enough to represent all Unicode *code points*.  It was when Java was designed, but then Unicode added more code planes.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, but I was able to solve it using:

```
if (str.substring(0,1).equals("x") )
```

the substring can be used in a loop str.substring(i, i + 1)

charAt(i).equals('x') will not work together

Answer (score 0):

.equals() can still be used, but you have to remember that chars require apostrophes(') instead of quotes("). For example: someChar.equals('c') is valid for chars and someString.equals("c") is valid for strings.

Comment: While `someChar.equals('c')` is technically correct code, it is doing unnecessary auto-boxing.  That may involve a runtime overhead (depending on how smart the JIT compiler is).